# Gnuplot: How to remove vectors below a certain magnitude from vector field?

Tags: vector, field, gnuplot

I have a 2D CFD code that gives me the x and y flow velocity at every point on a grid. I am currently visualizing the data using a vector field in gnuplot. My goal is to see how far the plume from an eruption extends, so it would be much cleaner if I could prevent vectors from showing up at all in the field if they fall below a certain magnitude. Does anyone have an idea how to go about this? My current gnuplot script is below. I can also modify the input file as necessary.

```
reset
set nokey
set term png
set xrange [0:5.1]
set yrange [0:10.1]
do for [i=0:10] {
    set title 'Eruption simulation: Timestep '.i
    set output 'path/FlowVel'.sprintf('%04.0f',i).'.png'
    plot 'path/Flow'.sprintf('%04.0f',i).'.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with vec
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a kind of filtering, which gnuplot doesn't really have, but can be achieved with the following trick (taken from "help using examples" in gnuplot):

```
 One trick is to use the ternary `?:` operator to filter data:

       plot 'file' using 1:($3>10 ? $2 : 1/0)

 which plots the datum in column two against that in column one provided
 the datum in column three exceeds ten.  `1/0` is undefined; `gnuplot`
 quietly ignores undefined points, so unsuitable points are suppressed.
 Or you can use the pre-defined variable NaN to achieve the same result.
```

So I guess you would want something like this in your case

```
plot "data.dat" u 1:2:($3**2+$4**2>mag_sq?$3:NaN):($3**2+$4**2>mag_sq?$4:NaN) w vector
```

where mag_sq is the square of your desired magnitude.